# mysql query to calculate student grades rows to get an order by asc or desc

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql database table examinations student is appearing based on subjects he/she wrote, the bellow query is outputting students who sat for EXAM tagged assessment_id = 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT exam.fname, exam.lname, exam.idcandidate
FROM examinations
AS exam
INNER JOIN examinfo 
AS info
ON exam.subject_id = info.subjectid
WHERE info.assessment_id = '1'
```

Now i would like to sort the query based on total scores a student have on his/her subjects either DESC or ASC

The field which stores student scores is called '**score**' from examinations table, PLEASE help me how i can archive this or what is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: [Read the manual for the `SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) (specifically `ORDER BY`)

Comment: u didn't understand me am not looking for order by score desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total is calculated for each exam.fname and each exam.lname and each exam.idcandidate

```
SELECT exam.fname, exam.lname, exam.idcandidate, sum(exam.score) total
from examinations exam
     inner join examinfo info   
on exam.subject_id = info.subjectid
where info.assessment_id = '1'
group by exam.fname, exam.lname, exam.idcandidate
order by total desc;
```

Total is calculated for each exam.idcandidate

```
SELECT distinct exam.fname, exam.lname, exam.idcandidate
from examinations exam
     inner join examinfo info 
     on exam.subject_id = info.subjectid
     inner join (select idcandidate, sum(score) total from examinations group by idcandidate) tot 
     on exam.idcandidate = tot.idcandidate
where info.assessment_id = '1'
order by tot.idcandidate desc;
```

Total is calculated for each exam.idcandidate (for assessment_id = '1')

```
SELECT distinct exam.fname, exam.lname, exam.idcandidate
from examinations exam
     inner join examinfo info 
     on exam.subject_id = info.subjectid
     inner join (select ex.idcandidate, sum(ex.score) total 
                  from examinations ex inner join examinfo ei 
                    on ex.subject_id = ei.subjectid 
                 where ei.assessment_id = '1' group by idcandidate) tot 
     on exam.idcandidate = tot.idcandidate
where info.assessment_id = '1'
order by tot.idcandidate desc;
```

Comment: hey multisync thanks for your response the first query works fine